algorithm/logic for a unique matrix sorting problem
I have a matrix sorting problem where each row contains at least two numbers, with the rest of the columns being None. I need to sort this matrix such that:

Each column is in increasing order, allowing None values between the numbers.
Each number appears only once per column.
If two rows have overlapping values in one or more columns (i.e., they share the same number in at least one column and do not have conflicting values), they should be combined into a single row.

Valid and Invalid Combinations:

Valid Combination:

[1, 2, None, None] and [None, 2, 3, None] can be combined to [1, 2, 3, None] since they share the value 2 in the second column and have no conflicting values.


Invalid Combination:

[1, 2, None, None] and [None, None, 3, 4] cannot be combined because they share no common numbers in any column.
[1, 2, None, None] and [2, 2, None, None] cannot be combined due to conflicting values in the first column.



By the end of this process, the matrix should be sorted such that:

Each number appears no more than once per column.
Each column is in increasing order.
If the process is impossible (e.g., no valid combination exists), the function should return False.

Problem Example:
Consider the following matrix:
matrix = [
    [1, 2, None, None],
    [None, None, 3, 4],
    [3, 5, None, None]
]

Now, I want to insert a new row:
new_row = [None, 1, 6, None]

My current approach checks the allowed ranges for the numbers in the new row. It detects:

1 can only be placed above the first row.

6 can only be placed after the second or third row.
Since there is no overlap in the allowed ranges for 1 and 6, the algorithm concludes that inserting the new row is impossible. However, we can see that by rearranging the matrix to:
[
    [None, None, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, None, None],
    [3, 5, None, None]
]




Questions:

How can I improve the logic for inserting a row or sorting the matrix so that it robustly handles these cases?
Are there any mathematical concepts or algorithms that could apply to this problem and help me optimize or simplify the solution? Specifically, I am interested in how to identify and generalize "detached" sections of the matrix, as seen in the example where the left two columns are independent of the right two columns.

In my current approach, I assume that we are given a sorted matrix and a new row that needs to be inserted while maintaining the following rules:

Each column remains in increasing order.
Numbers can only appear once in each column.
If any numbers overlap in a row, they must remain in the same row.

Here’s how the approach works:

Check if numbers in the new row have appeared in their respective columns:

For each number in the new row, the algorithm searches if that number has already appeared in its corresponding column in the matrix.
If a number has appeared in its column, then the new row's number must be inserted into the same row as the one where the number previously appeared.


Handle cases where no numbers have appeared before:

If none of the numbers in the new row have appeared in their columns before, the algorithm:

Determines the allowed range for each number to be inserted (i.e., positions where the number can be placed while maintaining increasing order in the column).
Finds the overlap of the allowed ranges for all the numbers in the new row.
If there is a valid overlap, the new row can be inserted at the first available position within that overlapping range.




Return false if no valid position is found:

If there is no overlap in the allowed ranges of the numbers, the algorithm concludes that it is impossible to insert the row without breaking the rules and returns False.




If you ask to improve something you should show the current state. I.e. consider providing a [mre] of your best attempt. I also get the impression that you could split this into multiple separate questions (but post only the first one immediatly), in order to increase the impression of a focused question (questions with lack of focus are off-topic you now...).

I think that trying to treat this as a matrix is not contributing anything, instead treat it as collection of items, each with a list of numbers in.
The the algorithm splits into 3 sequential steps

Combine any items which can be combined according to your "valid combinations"
Sort the items. According to a comparison which sorts on the first item in the list of numbers, if either first numbers is None, move onto the second item in the list of numbers....., if there's no overlap they you don't care
Check that every column has been simultaneously sorted, if any are wrong then return false.

Then after the algorithm you can build a matrix again if you want.

Thanks! I think this is what I was missing. I got caught in trying to solve the problem all in one step.


[1, 2, None, None] and [None, None, 3, 4] cannot be combined because they share no common numbers in any column

This does not seem like a useful constraint. Imagine you start with an empty matrix: then by definition you can never insert any rows, because there will never be anything to match on. Your program logic can detect whether a merge will happen or not.

we can see that by rearranging the matrix to:

This thought is incomplete, so I am disregarding it.

How can I improve the logic for inserting a row or sorting the matrix so that it robustly handles these cases?

Don't write matrix sorting logic at all. Only write logic for insertion to maintain order.

Are there any mathematical concepts or algorithms that could apply to this problem and help me optimize or simplify the solution?

Once you understand the demonstration below, extend it to cache copies of the column vectors such that only non-null elements are stored along with their indices in the original column, apply bisect, and (carefully) update the columns and their caches in an incremental manner. Add unit tests.

I am interested in how to identify and generalize "detached" sections of the matrix

This seems complex, and may require more effort to construct and maintain index structures than just running a bisection search on each column until you run into either a conflict or no more columns. In effect, the way that the demonstration below expresses column inter-dependence is to establish insertion ranges for each column; if the insertion range for any two columns produces a disjoint set from an intersection, then they conflict.
To demonstrate a simple implementation,
import typing


def none_or_greater_eq(
    col: typing.Sequence[int | None],
    cell: int,
) -> int:
    none_idx = None
    for i, val in enumerate(col):
        if val is None:
            none_idx = i
        elif val >= cell:
            if none_idx is not None:
                return none_idx
            return i
        else:
            none_idx = None
    if none_idx is not None:
        return none_idx
    return len(col)


def none_or_greater(
    col: typing.Sequence[int | None],
    cell: int,
    start: int,
) -> int:
    for i, val in enumerate(col[start:], start=start):
        if val is not None and val > cell:
            return i
    return len(col)


def place_cell(
    col: typing.Sequence[int | None],
    cell: int | None,
) -> tuple[
    int,  # min index
    int,  # max index
    bool,  # must merge
]:
    if cell is None:
        # Can go anywhere, no merge
        return 0, len(col), False

    # This non-null sequence could be cached and incrementally updated at the class level.
    # For simplicity, that isn't done in this demonstration.
    # If you do have a cached copy of a non-null sequence, then don't iterate; use bisect() instead.
    start = none_or_greater_eq(col, cell)
    if start < len(col) and col[start] == cell:
        # Must merge
        return start, start, True

    end = none_or_greater(col, cell, start)
    return start, end, False


class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, width: int) -> None:
        self.cols: list[list[int | None]] = [
            [] for _ in range(width)
        ]

    def place_row(self, row: typing.Sequence[int | None],
    ) -> tuple[
        int,   # y index
        bool,  # merge
    ]:
        """
        Identifies the insertion index and whether a merge is necessary. Does not mutate.
        """
        if len(self.cols[0]) < 3:  # delete me
            return len(self.cols[0]), False
        imins, imaxes, merges = zip(*(
            place_cell(col, cell)
            for col, cell in zip(self.cols, row)
        ))
        imin = max(imins)
        imax = min(imaxes)
        if imin > imax:
            raise IndexError(
                f'Cannot place due to conflict: must insert {imin} or after, {imax} or before'
            )
        return imax, any(merges)

    def insert_or_merge(
        self,
        y: int,
        merge: bool,
        row: typing.Sequence[int | None],
    ) -> None:
        for x, col in enumerate(self.cols):
            if merge:
                if row[x] is not None:
                    col[y] = row[x]
            else:
                col.insert(y, row[x])


def test() -> None:
    matrix = Matrix(width=4)
    matrix.insert_or_merge(0, False, (   1,    2, None, None))
    matrix.insert_or_merge(1, False, (None, None,    3,    4))
    matrix.insert_or_merge(2, False, (   3,    5, None, None))

    # All examples provided by OP

    try:
        matrix.place_row((None, 1, 6, None))
        raise AssertionError('should have thrown')
    except IndexError:
        pass

    row = (None, 2, 3, None)
    y, merge = matrix.place_row(row)
    assert y == 0
    assert merge
    # matrix.insert_or_merge(y, merge, row)

    row = (None, None, 3, 4)
    y, merge = matrix.place_row(row)
    assert y == 3
    assert not merge
    # matrix.insert_or_merge(y, merge, row)

    row = (2, 2, None, None)
    try:
        matrix.place_row(row)
        raise AssertionError('should havea thrown')
    except IndexError:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()

